# Java Swing passing variables to JFreeChart class

Tags: java, swing, variables, jfreechart

I need help with last one thing in my project. I need to pass 4 variables (named a, b, c and d) from JDialog to JFreeChart in another class. I have added checkpoints to see where it actually stops to be processed and the code is as follows:

```
package calc.kalkulator;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

class PanelFunkcji extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
    private JLabel lA, lB, lC, lD;
    private JTextField tA, tB, tC, tD;
    private JButton bOK, bCancel;
    private OknoFunkcji oknoFunkcji;
    public double dA, dB, dC, dD;






public PanelFunkcji(JFrame owner) {
    super(owner, "Wprowadzanie funkcji", true);
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLayout(null);

    bOK = new JButton("OK");
    bOK.setBounds(10, 40, 130, 20);
    add(bOK);
    bOK.addActionListener(this);

    bCancel = new JButton("Anuluj");
    bCancel.setBounds(150, 40, 130, 20);
    add(bCancel);
    bCancel.addActionListener(this);

    lA = new JLabel("A = ");
    lA.setBounds(10, 70, 40, 20);
    add(lA);

    tA = new JTextField("0");
    tA.setBounds(50, 70, 60, 20);
    add(tA);

    lB = new JLabel("B = ");
    lB.setBounds(10, 100, 40, 20);
    add(lB);

    tB = new JTextField("0");
    tB.setBounds(50, 100, 60, 20);
    add(tB);

    lC = new JLabel("C = ");
    lC.setBounds(10, 130, 40, 20);
    add(lC);

    tC = new JTextField("0");
    tC.setBounds(50, 130, 60, 20);
    add(tC);

    lD = new JLabel("D = ");
    lD.setBounds(10, 160, 40, 20);
    add(lD);

    tD = new JTextField("0");
    tD.setBounds(50, 160, 60, 20);
    add(tD);

}

public double getA() {
    return Double.parseDouble(tA.getText());
}

public double getB() {
    return Double.parseDouble(tB.getText());
}

public double getC() {
    return Double.parseDouble(tC.getText());
}

public double getD() {
    return Double.parseDouble(tD.getText());
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object z = e.getSource(); 
    if(z == bOK) {
        dA = getA();
        dB = getB();
        dC = getC();
        dD = getD();
        System.out.println("1st checkpoint: A " + dA + " B " + dB + " C " + dC + " D " + dD);
        if (oknoFunkcji == null) {
            oknoFunkcji = new OknoFunkcji("Wykres");
        }
        oknoFunkcji.setVisible(true);
        //setVisible(false);
    }
    else if (z == bCancel) {
        setVisible(false);          
    }   
}   
}
```

The class I am trying to pass the variables to is this one:

```
package calc.kalkulator;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.*;

class OknoFunkcji extends ApplicationFrame {

private static PanelFunkcji panelFunkcji;
private static double a;
private static double b;
private static double c;
private static double d;

public void getDane () {
    a = panelFunkcji.dA;
    b = panelFunkcji.dB;
    c = panelFunkcji.dC;
    d = panelFunkcji.dD;
    System.out.println("2nd checkpoint: A " + a + " B " + b + " C " + c + " D " + d);
}


public OknoFunkcji(String title) {
    super(title);
    JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();

    panelFunkcji = new PanelFunkcji(new JFrame()); 
    chartPanel.setSize(500, 270);
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
    getDane();
    System.out.println("3rd checkpoint: A " + a + " B " + b + " C " + c + " D " + d);


}

/**
 * Tworzy chart.
 * 
 * @param dataset - zbiór danych.
 * 
 * @return Zwraca instancję charta.
 */
private static JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset) {
    // create the chart...
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
        " ",       // chart title
        "X",                      // x axis label
        "Y",                      // y axis label
        dataset,                  // data
        PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,  
        true,                     // include legend
        true,                     // tooltips
        false                     // urls
    );

    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
    plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);
    plot.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0);
    return chart;
}

/**
 * Creates a sample dataset.
 * 
 * @return A sample dataset.
 */
public static XYDataset createDataset() {
    XYDataset result = DatasetUtilities.sampleFunction2D(new X2(), 
            -10.0, 10.0, 40, "f(x)");
    return result;
}

public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
    return new ChartPanel(chart);
}

static class X2 implements Function2D {

    public double getValue(double x) {
        return a*x*x*x + b*x*x + c*x + d;
    }

}



}
```

And what I get printed in console is this:

```
 1st checkpoint: A 1.0 B 2.0 C 3.0 D 4.0
 2nd checkpoint: A 0.0 B 0.0 C 0.0 D 0.0
 3rd checkpoint: A 0.0 B 0.0 C 0.0 D 0.0
```

So it is not actually the parsing that's making things go bad, and either it is REALLY simple and I am just missing a point or it is impossible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the point. The problem is that you have a reference in `OknoFunkcji` to `PanelFunkcji`.

Here you are creating a new instance, and you don't want to have a new instance of this JPanel. Besides you are not adding it to any container.

```
panelFunkcji = new PanelFunkcji(new JFrame());
```

This class `PanelFunkcji` **use** `OknoFunkcji` and not viceversa. So when you create a new instance of `OknoFunkcji` you have to pass that values via constructor injection or setter injection. For example you could do something like this.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object z = e.getSource(); 
    if(z == bOK) {
        dA = getA();
        dB = getB();
        dC = getC();
        dD = getD();
        System.out.println("1st checkpoint: A " + dA + " B " + dB + " C " + dC + " D " + dD);
        if (oknoFunkcji == null) {
            oknoFunkcji = new OknoFunkcji("Wykres");
        }
        oknoFunkcji.createChart(dA,dB,dC,dD); // added this method 
        oknoFunkcji.setVisible(true);
        //setVisible(false);
    }
    else if (z == bCancel) {
        setVisible(false);          
    }   
}
```

And in your another class

```
  public OknoFunkcji(String title) {
         super(title);
         System.out.println("3rd checkpoint: A " + a + " B " + b + " C " + c + " D " + d);
  }

  public void createChart(double dA, double dB, double dC, double dD) {
        setData(dA,dB,dC,dD);
        JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
        chartPanel.setSize(500, 270);
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
        revalidate();
        repaint();        
    }

    public void setData(double dA, double dB, double dC, double dD) {
        a = dA;
        b = dB;
        c = dC;
        d = dD;
        System.out.println("2nd checkpoint: A " + a + " B " + b + " C " + c + " D " + d);
    }
```

As a side note and not less important you should not make your variables and all your methods `static` cause then there is no practical reason to create instances of that class. 
Don't use `null layout` learn about using [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: @nachokk
Applied the changes you told about and now the result in console is like this:
`1st checkpoint: A 1.0 B 2.0 C 3.0 D 4.0
3rd checkpoint: A 0.0 B 0.0 C 0.0 D 0.0
2nd checkpoint: A 1.0 B 2.0 C 3.0 D 4.0`

In this order. And if the graph is correctly coded, then it isn't getting the a, b, c and d variables (shows f(x) = 0).

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! I don't even know how to thank you for this!