# How insert Variable from one class into class with JFreeChart to plot this variable?

Tags: java, jfreechart

Update question[Update]`*`: 
`*` - in the code
[Termometr shows 0 - screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2yuN.png)

Why I can't insert variable `temp` from `DBData.java` in to `final DefaultValueDataset dataset = new DefaultValueDataset(new Double(temp));` in Tempo.java  [ I want to place it in the dataset, I want plot chart like termometr with value of `temp` from DBData.java ]

I know that in DBData.java in `void ConnectDB()` `TemperaturaPow` is String so  I parse it to double. 
I tried parse `temp` to integer but without result.

In Tempo.java I can use System.out.println(dbData.temp) and IDEA shows me for example 9.0 but JFreeChart Termometr is showing value "0" zero

Tempo.java

```
public class Tempo extends ApplicationFrame {

public Tempo(final String title){

    super(title);

    DBData dbData = new DBData();
    final double temp = dbData.temp;

    final DefaultValueDataset dataset = new DefaultValueDataset(new Double(temp)); <<<-------

    final ThermometerPlot plot = new ThermometerPlot(dataset);
    final JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Termometr",JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT,plot,false);

    plot.setThermometerStroke(new BasicStroke(2.0f));
    plot.setThermometerPaint(Color.lightGray);

    final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    DBData dbData = new DBData();
    dbData.ConnectDB();
    final Tempo demo = new Tempo("Thermometr demo");
    demo.pack();
    demo.setVisible(true);
   System.out.println(dbData.temp);

}
```

}

DBData.java

```
public class DBData {

    public double temp;
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    void ConnectDB(){

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://XXX
                    "passs");
            st = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Połączono z BD");

            String query = "SELECT * FROM X ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from MySQL");

            while (rs.next()) {
                String TemperaturaPow = rs.getString("TemperaturaPow");
                System.out.println(TemperaturaPow);
                temp = Double.parseDouble(TemperaturaPow); <<<----------
                System.out.println(temp);


            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }

    void initialize(){
        ConnectDB();
    }

}
```

[Update]*

I added try in `DBData.java` to check does it parse to double.

```
while (rs.next()) {
                String TemperaturaPow = rs.getString("TemperaturaPow");
                System.out.println(TemperaturaPow);
                temp = Double.parseDouble(TemperaturaPow); <<<----------
                System.out.println(temp);
                try{
                    temp = Integer.parseInt(TemperaturaPow);
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Error parse: " + e);
                }
Intellji prints for me :

Error parse: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7.7"
0.0
0.0
If I use :

try{
                    temp = Double.parseDouble(TemperaturaPow);
                }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                    System.out.println("Error parse: " + e);
                }
```

Intellji prints for me :

7.7
7.7
But thermometr can't draw - it receive null or 0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Changing mercury color in thermometer in JFreeChart*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7597015/230513).

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291386/java-swing-passing-variables-to-jfreechart-class) this is similar topic but I don't understand it :/ question is why `DefaultValueDataset dataset` in Tempo.java can't take variable `temp` from other class and draw chart/show temperature in termometr - termometr shows 0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this example is :

In `DBData.java`, we have method which take data from MySQL = `ConnectDB()`.
This method must be `public double ConnectDB()` and this method must return variable `temp`:

```
public double DBConnect(){
...code...
return temp;
}
```

In class where I have code to draw chart we need to :

```
DBData dbData = new DBData();
double temp = dbData.ConnectDB();
```

and then we can insert variable temp into dataset

```
   final DefaultValueDataset dataset = new DefaultValueDataset(new Double(temp));
```

Working `JFreeChart` like thermometer [image: screen of working chart]